# Why txtSearch is Null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
<div>
    Search by name:
    <input type="text" name="txtSearch" />
    @Html.ActionLink("Search", "SearchName") 
</div>
```

txtSearch in this code is null

```
public ActionResult SearchName(string txtSearch)
{
    var model = blShoperInfo.Select().Where(p => p.Name.Contains(txtSearch));
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

i can not use form(formMethod) Because in the view Form method is set for another action What do I do now? Whether the two methods form a view as possible?

Comment: Because your not sending any data to your method. You need a form (with `FormMethod.Get`) to post the value of the textbox (or dynamically update the `href` attribute of your link using javascript)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can have as many forms in a view as you want so long as they are not nested. You need to show more details of what your trying to do.